# oauth-private.key does not exist or is not readable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I clone a project from gitlab written by Laravel Framework 6.13.1 that use passport library.
As usual I first executed **composer install** but i got this error :

```
   LogicException  : Key path "file://C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\storage\oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\CryptKey.php:48
    44|             $keyPath = 'file://' . $keyPath;
    45|         }
    46|
    47|         if (!file_exists($keyPath) || !is_readable($keyPath)) {
  > 48|             throw new LogicException(sprintf('Key path "%s" does not exist or is not readable', $keyPath));
    49|         }
    50|
    51|         if ($keyPermissionsCheck === true) {
    52|             // Verify the permissions of the key

  Exception trace:

  1   League\OAuth2\Server\CryptKey::__construct("file://C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\storage\oauth-private.key")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\note-server\vendor\laravel\passport\src\PassportServiceProvider.php:248

  2   Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::makeCryptKey("private")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\note-server\vendor\laravel\passport\src\PassportServiceProvider.php:214
```

**now i can not run php artisan command i got same Error**

where is the problem? why i got this error? i search it in internet some one say run **php artisan passport:install** or other command but i can not now run **php artiasan** because got same error

Comment: try: php artisan passport:install

Comment: Give the permission `sudo chown www-data:www-data storage/oauth-*.key`

Comment: @sta : i use windows

Comment: `oauth-private.key` file exist on 
 _\myproject\storage_ ?

Comment: @sta : no i clone porject from gitlab

Answer (score 12):

Since **/storage/*.key** is in **.gitignore** so if you pull the project, that might be missing the key by running

```
 php artisan passport:keys
```

will generate new keys for you.

Comment: your answer is incorrect , as i mentioned i can not run this command because i do not have access to php artisan, if i run php artisan .... i got same error

Comment: remove the vendor folder and then run **composer update**

Comment: not work. after delete vendor and try composer update or install i got same error

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack and I just used it to get my test environment working so I wouldn't recommend to do this for production environments but I managed to get this working by doing the following before running `composer install`:

I first generated the keys manually:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ./storage/id_rsa && mv ./storage/id_rsa ./storage/oauth-private.key && mv ./storage/id_rsa.pub ./storage/oauth-public.key
```

Then I ensured that a valid `APP_KEY` was in my `.env` file by running `php artisan key:generate` on another machine and including it in the repository; you could also add it to the `.env` file manually. The main reason this is unsafe is because that key shouldn't be included in any repositories and should exist only on its own machine for security reasons.

This should get the build in a state where you can run `composer install` and afterwards run the following to install passport:

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan passport:install --force
```

Hopefully everything should then be in a working state.

Again, this is a hack I used to get my test environment working as I assumed there was some sort of compatibility issue with my versions of Laravel/Passport and the machine itself.

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution for this passport bug.

```
 'api' => [
        'driver' => file_exists('file://'.Passport::keyPath('oauth-public.key')) ? 'passport' : 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
```