# A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I'm creating an API with laravel. I have used laravel passport for api authentication.
I am getting this error while deploying my code to heroku.
I used git for depploy in heroku. When I run `git push heroku master` I am getting this error.

```
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
remote:        > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
remote:        
remote:        In CryptKey.php line 52:
remote:                                                                                       
remote:          Key path "file:///tmp/build_a8bd6864/storage/oauth-private.key" does not ex  
remote:          ist or is not readable                                                       
remote:                                                                                       
remote:        
remote:        Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
remote:  !     WARNING: A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error
remote: 
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
remote:  !     
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:  !     
remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
remote:  !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
remote:  !     - A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 2084aa011f3c0e5b395af053a556d46d7d1e3a1f
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 2084aa011f3c0e5b395af053a556d46d7d1e3a1f
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to minute-man-api.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/minute-man-api.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/minute-api.git'
```

I am getting this error while deploying my code to heroku.
I used git for depploy in heroku. When I run `git push heroku master` I am getting this error.

Here is composer.json file.

```
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/nexmo-notification-channel": "^2.4",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

How solve this?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you put your `composer.json` file ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul I have added composer.json file. Please check.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AuthServiceProvider.php` you should not check if the key exists or not in storage.

And in `.gitinnore` file comment `/storage/*.key` line like this `# /storage/*.key`

Then after deploying to heroku generate passpot key.

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on another I posted [on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66173517/616589). To reiterate what I posted there, the following is a hack.

Since I don't think you're able to alter the heroku initialisation without creating your own custom buildpack you'll need to rely on the `scripts`. Add the following in your `scripts` section of `composer.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "if test -f 'storage/oauth-public.key'; then @php artisan package:discover --ansi; fi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ./storage/id_rsa && mv ./storage/id_rsa ./storage/oauth-private.key && mv ./storage/id_rsa.pub ./storage/oauth-public.key",
        "@php artisan clear-compiled",
        "@php artisan optimize",
        "@php artisan migrate --force",
        "@php artisan passport:install --force"
    ],
}
```

To explain: `post-autoload-dump` runs first so there's a check to make sure the key files exist before running `package:discover`. Next `post-install-cmd` will run and this creates some temporary key files to get everything running before then running everything to install passport.

I experienced a second issue where it couldn't run because there wasn't a valid `APP_KEY` so you might need to add an `.env` file to your repository containing a key generated on another machine. You should change that once everything is up and running as having an app key off the machine is a security risk.